# Can forfiles search multiple drives in the same command and create a txt file of results?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scripting, windows-command-prompt

Can `forfiles` search multiple drives in the same command and create a text file of results?  I have the following that works to show me the results in command prompt but what I really need is a `.txt` file that displays all the matches.

Also, if there was a way of searching `C:\` and `D:\` in the same instance?

```
forfiles /p c:\ /s /m XYZ*.* /d -15 /c "cmd /c echo @file is a txt file and older then 15 days
```

I have adjusted the line so that it outputs a text file in the folder that command prompt is opening from so that part is done but I am still trying to figure out how to scan the `C:` and the `D:` in the same command. The new line is:

```
forfiles /p c:\ /s /m XYZ*.* /d -15 /c "cmd /c echo @path" >outputC.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a `.bat` file with the following text and it gave me what I was hoping to accomplish:

```
forfiles /p c:\ /s /m *XYZ*.* /d -15 /c "cmd /c echo @path" >outputC.txt


forfiles /p d:\ /s /m *XYZ*.* /d -15 /c "cmd /c echo @path" >outputD.txt
```

Separating the lines with the enter key created the two separate text output files.